# How to best set up MS project when different resources have different work speed

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2010

I am new to MS project and need to set up a plan with different resources.

One thing I am aware of is that we have experienced programmers and very junior programmers. The more junior ones tend to be given more time for a task, whilst the more experienced ones need less time.

So e.g. the junior worker will be expected to work efficiently 4 hours, the more experienced ones 7 hours.

However in other tasks, e.g. when writing technical concepts, everybody is usually regarded "equal", I.e. expected to work effectively 7 hours a day.

What is the best way to model this in MS project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just enter the work estimates for each resource as you assignment them to the task.  Project will then calculate the duration of the task based upon the Work/Units.

For the junior programmer, because there is more work (effort) required to produce a product - it will take more time (duration) to complete the task.

Comment: But that does not give you the ability to have the software level work and automatically assign between the different developers - you are basically saying 'do the leveling and assignments yourself'. Makes Project just a drawing tool...

Comment: Why would assigning work remove the ability to have Project level resources?  As far as "do the leveling and assignments yourself" - Project has never automatically assigned resources to tasks.  I guess I'm not understanding your comment.

Comment: I meant when you have multiple resources (with different work speeds, in this example) for the same type of work, and multiple tasks for them, you can use Project to distribute work between them so all keep busy and all task get finished. With this approach, as I have to adjust task work according to the resource, I need to do it myself - if resource 1 takes two weeks longer for his tasks then all others, I need to move some of his tasks to other resources *and adjust the hours on them manually for those resources' effectivity*

Comment: It would have been nice if the system could sort that out for me. I thought this was the original question (but I see now it wasn't)

Comment: Sorry.  If you have a question - you may wish to start a new thread.